# function with 'load.Rdata' in for loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I write a function with for-loop and the for-loop is using `load.Rdata`. Here is my sample function.

```
tmp_fun = function(list_dtaname){
  for (ii in 1:length(list_dtaname)) {
    filename0 = paste(list_dtaname[ii],'.RData',sep = '')
    miceadds::load.Rdata(filename0, "dta00")
    rm(dta00)
  }
```

}

When I use this function

`tmp_fun(samplelist)`

I get this result

```
tmp_fun(list_pot_dtaname$out)
Warning messages:
1: In rm(dta00) : object 'dta00' not found
2: In rm(dta00) : object 'dta00' not found
3: In rm(dta00) : object 'dta00' not found
4: In rm(dta00) : object 'dta00' not found
5: In rm(dta00) : object 'dta00' not found
6: In rm(dta00) : object 'dta00' not found
7: In rm(dta00) : object 'dta00' not found
```

why the function is not working?

Comment: I haven't created the 'dta00'

Comment: still have the same warnings.. What I am trying to do with the original code is to keep updating data by using 'miceadds::load.Rdata(filename0, "dta00")' and the I do something with the updated "dta00" in every for-loop iteration

Comment: so, my concern is not the 'rm(dta00)', my code doesn't seem to keep updating data from the load.Rdata

Comment: If I don't use function, there is no problem

Comment: that's why I load, delete and load again delete,,,,

Comment: Can you try `dta00 <- miceadds::load.Rdata2( filename= paste(list_dtaname[ii],'.RData',sep = ''));
rm(dta00)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could change it to `load.Rdata2` where there is an option to specify the `path` (instead of 'objname' to be created) and the assignment can be done on the lhs of `<-` to a temporary object which we `rm`

```
tmp_fun <- function(list_dtaname){
  for (ii in 1:length(list_dtaname)) {
    filename0 = paste(list_dtaname[ii],'.RData',sep = '')
   dta00 <- miceadds::load.Rdata2(filename=
          paste(list_dtaname[ii],'.RData',sep = ''))
    rm(dta00)
  }
}
```

---

The issue in `load.Rdata` would be where the object gets saved.  According to `?load.Rdata`

> The function load.Rdata saves the loaded object in the global environment while load.Rdata2 loads the object only specified environments